# Compiler dependency in right shift operator on signed types:

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, signed, octal

In the following code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
main()
{
    int y=-01;
    y<<=3;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    y>>=3;
    printf("%d",y);
    getch();
}
```

I read in a book that while using the right shift operator on y, the signed bit may or may not be preserved depending on my compiler. Why is that? What is the concept behind this? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some processors have only an "unsigned" right shift (fills the sign bit with 0's) or a signed right shift (fills the size bit with copies of the current sign bit). Since some processors only have one or the other, but not both, the standard doesn't try to mandate one behavior or the other.

For what it's worth, many (most?) current processors have instructions to do both. For example, the x86 includes both `shr` (logical shift right -- fills with 0's) and `sar` (arithmetic shift right -- fills with copies of the sign bit).

Answer (score 2):

The following quotes from the C11 standard (**6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators**)might be helpful :

> - The result of **E1 << E2** is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated    bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is **E1 × 2^E2**, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and    nonnegative value, and **E1 × 2^E2** is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.
> - The result of **E1 >> E2** is E1 **right-shifted** E2 bit positions. If E1    has an unsigned type or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral part of the quotient of **E1 / 2^E2**. **If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the  resulting value is implementation-defined.**

Answer (score 0):

lets see this example

consider this value   `1111 1111 1111 1111`

if your compiler is 16 bit you did right shift

value will become `1111 1111 1111 1110`

if your compiler is 32 bit and you did right shift

value will become     `0000 0000 0000 0001 1111 1111 1111 1110`

you did the right shift of same value but you will get different result depending up on your compiler.

use **%x** to print the hexa decimal notation of decimal value.

see this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
   int y=-01;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",y);

    y<<=3;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",y);
    y>>=3;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",y);


    y=127;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",y);

    y<<=3;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",y);
    y>>=3;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",y);


    y=32767;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",y);

    y<<=3;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",y);
    y>>=3;
    printf("%d\n",y);
    printf("%x\n",y);


    getchar();
}
```

OUTPUT ON 64-bit machine :

-1
ffffffff
-8
fffffff8
-1
ffffffff
127
7f
1016
3f8
127
7f
32767
7fff
262136
3fff8
32767
7fff

OUTPUT ON 32-bit machine :

-1
ffffffff
-8
fffffff8
-1
ffffffff
127
7f
1016
3f8
127
7f
32767
7fff
-8
fffffff8
-1
ffffffff

when reaches to maximum value of 32 bit signed integers , you will find the compiler dependency on shifting.

here 8-bit signed integers explained with 1's and 2's compliment representation
 [Signed number representations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations)

Answer (score 0):

This is true. Because, there are four types of shifting available.

1. [Arithmetic Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_shift)
2. [Logical Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_shift)
3. [Rotate No carry Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Rotate_no_carry)
4. [Rotate Through Carry Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Rotate_through_carry)

In first two types, the position of `sign-bit` is preserved while shifting shifting to the right or left. Generally in the C or any derivation of C uses the `Arithmetic Shift` & `Logical Shift`. In C, the `Right Shift` is `Arithmetic Shift` & `Left Shift` is Logical. But in Java, both shifting are `Logical Shifting`.

In the last two types, the positioned of the `Sign Bit` are not maintained. The bits are shifted in regular manner. The `Rotate No Carry` falls under the [Circular Shift](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_shift) which is mostly used in cryptography to retain all the bits.

The C Programming, although implements the `Logical & arithmetic Shift`, but it also has the capability to recognize the `Circular Shifting` in the following way:

```
unsigned int x;
unsigned int y;
/* This Code is Just for reference from Wikipedia */    
y = (x << shift) | (x >> (sizeof(x)*CHAR_BIT - shift));
```

I this information is not Sufficient, then you can go through the `Wikipedia` main article which is linked from the title of all the shifts above.